# Trying to use a macro to insert a matrix system inside the table

Tags: tables, macros, matrices

I have this code to generate the matrix below:

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{matrix} 
    \textcolor{blue}{LKC_1} \\
    \textcolor{blue}{LKC_2} &
\end{matrix}
\putunder{
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{R_1} & -\frac{1}{R_1}\\
        -\frac{1}{R_1} & \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}
    \end{bmatrix}
}
{
    \begin{matrix} 
        \textcolor{red}{Y}
    \end{matrix}
}
\end{gather}
```

[image]

And I have this code to generate this table below:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
    \normalsize
    \caption{Elements [...].}
    \label{tab:anm_estampas}
    \begin{center}
        %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
        \begin{tabular}{l | c | l | c }
            \hline Elements & Symbol    & Matricex  & Equantions  \\\hline
            Resistor        &       &           &   \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \fonte{Figuras do Autor}
\end{table}
```

And where is the blue arrow I want to put a macro to insert the matrix. I want to do that to not pollute with a lot of code inside the table.

[image]

So, to do that I caught all code that generates the matrix and put inside a macro like that:

```
\newcommand{\matrixresistor}{%
    \begin{gather}
        \begin{matrix} 
            \textcolor{blue}{LKC_1} \\
            \textcolor{blue}{LKC_2} &
        \end{matrix}
        \putunder{
            \begin{bmatrix}
                \frac{1}{R_1} & -\frac{1}{R_1}\\
                -\frac{1}{R_1} & \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}
            \end{bmatrix}
        }
        {
            \begin{matrix} 
                \textcolor{red}{Y}
            \end{matrix}
        }
    \end{gather}
}%
```

But this didn't work anyway. Throwing the error:

[image]

I couldn't discover what is the cause. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just change both `begin{gather}` and `\end{gather}` to `$` -- the token that initiates and terminates (inline) math mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `gather` in a normal `tabular` cell. You're using the wrong tool, I believe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col,last-row]
\textcolor{blue}{LKC_1} & \frac{1}{R_1} & -\frac{1}{R_1} \\[1.5ex]
\textcolor{blue}{LKC_2} & -\frac{1}{R_1} & \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2} \\[1ex]
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathcolor{red}{Y}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

The object I set in the math display can be used anywhere (in math mode).

[image]

You can define your symbol like as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\matrixresistor}{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col,last-row]
      \textcolor{blue}{LKC_1} & \frac{1}{R_1} & -\frac{1}{R_1} \\[1.5ex]
      \textcolor{blue}{LKC_2} & -\frac{1}{R_1} & \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2} \\[1ex]
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathcolor{red}{Y}}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l c l c }
\toprule
Elements & Symbol & Matrices        & Equations  \\
\midrule
Resistor &        & \matrixresistor &   \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Using `booktabs` commands is recommended, instead of ruled tables.

[image]

Comment: I've tried this, and setting it into macro and calling the macro inside the table I've got this error: Fatal Package nicematrix Error: The environment {bNiceMatrix} can be used

Comment: @Lucas Guimaraes: It's possible to insert a `{bNiceMatrix}` in a `{tabular}`: see my answer.

Comment: @LucasGuimaraes Please, see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the definition of `\matrixresistor`: I would like to suggest that you get rid of the `align` wrapper and, instead, use an `\ensuremath` directive. That way, the macro can be employed without knowing in advance if it'll be used while in text mode or math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath,booktabs,threeparttable}
\newcommand*{\putunder}[2]{{\displaystyle\mathop{#1}_{\textstyle #2}}} % ?
\newcommand{\matrixresistor}{\ensuremath{%
            \begin{matrix} 
              \textcolor{blue}{\mathit{LKC}_1} \\[1ex]
              \textcolor{blue}{\mathit{LKC}_2} 
            \end{matrix}%
            \putunder{%  
              \begin{bmatrix}
                   \frac{1}{R_1} & -\frac{1}{R_1}   \\[1ex]
                  -\frac{1}{R_1} &  \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}
              \end{bmatrix}
            }{ \textcolor{red}{Y} }
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Elements [...].}
    \label{tab:anm_estampas}
        \begin{tabular}{@{} lccc @{}}
            \toprule
            Elements & Symbol & Matricex          & Equantions  \\
            \midrule
            Resistor &        &  \matrixresistor  &   \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        
    \smallskip\footnotesize
    Fonte: Figuras do Autor
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\def\matrixresistor
{$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col,last-row]
\textcolor{blue}{LKC_1} & \frac{1}{R_1} & -\frac{1}{R_1} \\[1.5ex]
\textcolor{blue}{LKC_2} & -\frac{1}{R_1} & \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2} \\[1ex]
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mathcolor{red}{Y}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}$}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Elements & Symbol & Matricex & Equantions \\
\midrule
Resistor & & \matrixresistor \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]